# Call functions instead of reloading page

Tags: javascript, html

Basically I have this function that picks two different random images from a folder. At the moment I'm using `onClick="window.location.reload()` to run the function everytime you click.

Is there anyway I can call the funcion `onClick` without refreshing the page?

Thanks in advance.

```css
body {
  border: 0;
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font: 2.1vw/1.2em HelveticaNeue, Arial, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: .02em
}

.logo {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 100
}

#one,
#two {
  position: fixed;
  width: 50vw;
  top: 0;
  display: table
}

#one {
  left: 0;
  text-align: right
}

#two {
  right: 0;
  text-align: left
}

.inner {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw
}
```

```html
<script>
  var IMG = new Array()
  IMG[0] = 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0224/5205/products/Siser_EasyWeed_Bright_Red_2048x.jpg?v=1523704262'
  IMG[1] = 'http://thezilla.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/blue.png'
  IMG[2] = 'http://d18nh7ureywlth.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/6901-vibrant-green.jpg'

  var j = 0
  var p = IMG.length;
  var preBuffer = new Array()
  for (i = 0; i < p; i++) {
    preBuffer[i] = new Image()
    preBuffer[i].src = IMG[i]
  }
  var WI1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * p);
  var WI2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (p - 1));
  if (WI2 >= WI1) {
    WI2 += 1;
  }

  function showImage1() {
    document.write('<img src="' + IMG[WI1] + '">');
  }

  function showImage2() {
    document.write('<img src="' + IMG[WI2] + '">');
  }
</script>
<div class=logo onClick="window.location.reload()"><span class=inner>( RANDOM DYPTICHS )</span></div>
<div id=one><span class=inner><script>showImage1();</script></span></div>
<div id=two><span class=inner><script>showImage2();</script></span></div>
```

Comment: Look into using AJAX

Comment: Don't use `document.write()`.

Comment: You should make a function.

Comment: Look into [`AJAX`](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp)

Comment: "At the moment I'm using `onClick="window.location.reload()`" - Where is this in the code you provided?

Comment: @NickParsons it's all there inside the snippet no?

Comment: @NickParsons First div in the HTML in the question.

Comment: Put all the code into a function and change it to `onClick="yourNewFunctionName()"`, but there's a lot of other stuff that could (should?) change as well.  Quotes missing around things and inline event handlers, but that fix will at least get it doing what you ask.  Also, definitely drop `document.write()` as that kills the page contents.  You need to put images on the page and update the `src` attribute when you want to change them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally, there is no need to use ajax either.

I simply used an [`addEventListener('click'...)`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp) and [`encapsulated`](https://www.intertech.com/Blog/encapsulation-in-javascript/) your code.

Click on the screen and the images will change randomly.

> **To Note:** Take into a habit of adding (`;`) where is needed, Javascript is not strict (unless using `"use strict"`) on colons but it can cause a lot of bugs in the future. Also, use commas (`'` or `"`) in your attributes in `HTML`.
>
> Read [`Javascript Style Guide`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_conventions.asp) written by W3 Schools, they do a
> good job explaining to newbies about famous javascript conventions
> around the globe.

---

```js
var IMG = new Array(
  'https://i.picsum.photos/id/562/200/200.jpg?hmac=F4ylYRNFPH6rDzYo48_NUieJXXI2yaMl9ElwGeFQHZo',
  'https://i.picsum.photos/id/650/200/200.jpg?hmac=gu3C13pBxCSHokbnumczMYlmWRLt3CFGx1sDaPpfRnk',
  'https://i.picsum.photos/id/67/200/200.jpg?hmac=sN5XCCMqqmBvgDbYmAowWy2VToCkSYP5igDL_iRxK3M');

function getRandomImagePair() {
  var j = 0;
  var p = IMG.length;
  var preBuffer = new Array();

  for (i = 0; i < p; i++) {
    preBuffer[i] = new Image();
    preBuffer[i].src = IMG[i];
  }

  WI1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * p);
  WI2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (p - 1));

  if (WI2 >= WI1) {
    WI2 += 1;
  }

  document.querySelector('#imgOne').src = IMG[WI1];
  document.querySelector('#imgTwo').src = IMG[WI2];
}

getRandomImagePair();

document.querySelector('.logo .inner').addEventListener('click', e => {
  getRandomImagePair();
});
```

```css
body {
  border: 0;
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font: 2.1vw/1.2em HelveticaNeue, Arial, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: .02em
}

.logo {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 100;
}

#one,
#two {
  position: fixed;
  width: 50vw;
  top: 0;
  display: table
}

#one {
  left: 0;
  text-align: right
}

#two {
  right: 0;
  text-align: left
}

.inner {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw
}
```

```html
<div class='logo'><span class='inner'>( RANDOM DYPTICHS )</span></div>
<div id='one'><span class='inner'><img id="imgOne" src="#" /></span></div>
<div id='two'><span class='inner'><img id="imgTwo" src="#" /></span></div>
```

Comment: That's easily editable. If you so persist, I'll amend it now.

Comment: Ignore the comment about setting the image src attribute - I misread your answer and thought there were image tags.

Comment: hahaha, I'm just after changing it. P.S. Logo is spanned full screen so either-way, event will be the entire context.

Comment: @Federico glad to help out.